# Angular 9: The resource you are looking for has been removed

Tags: angular, azure, .net-6.0, azure-appservice

I have Angular 9 application with .NET 6 application deployed on Azure App Service. I am getting below error for specific routes and for specific records only when I refresh the page. It loads properly for the first time but on refresh, I am getting below error:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

For instance, I have one custom route called purchase orders. It works for most of all purchase orders but for some of them I am getting above error. Just a note that my route has encrypted id for specific records.

I have web.config with rewrite rule already and it works for most of all routes except few. Here is my rewrite rule:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.chunk.js|.js|.map|.js.gz|.css|.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico|.eot|.woff|.woff2|.ttf|.json|.html|ai.0.js|robots.txt|api|swagger)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"></conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index_po.html" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Updates(26/10/2022):

While investigating more, I found that only those urls are failing which has js or css word in it. Like:

https://test-app.azurewebsites.net/purchaseOrders/order-details/a/eyjoiMENBRmR1eXBUdVRaN2F****JS****lN1bUZ1QT09In0,

How should I avoid it to call Server/API?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you have `window.location.load`  anywhere in your application?

Comment: Nope, I am not using `window.location.load` anywhere in application.